# Structuring into a Laravel way approach

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to do things the Laravel way.

I'm rebuilding a custom cms. The idea is simple,

1) you have a page with a slug
2) a page can have components(widgets)

Each component had it's own controller file and view (Twig template).

The concept is

1) Get the slug
2) Get the page from the database with the slug
3) Get the components on the page
4) Render all the components (each component has a controller and view)
5) Render the page with the components. The page has it's own controller

So at this point, my 'hack' is working.

I can get the slug, retrieve the page, get the components, render the components and render the page.

But it ain't pretty

My starting point now is from the route

```
Route::get('{slug?}', function ($slug="/") {

// 1) get the slug
// 2) retrieve page from database 
// 3) retrieve components on that page from database
// 4) render each component (calling their controller) and return the html
// 5) render the page (it has it's own controller , the component html is passed into the controller) and output the html

})
```

These are a lot of logic just in this function and I want to reduce this.

I can ofcourse create a model for the page and component to get data from the database.
I don't want to create one page controller and then in that controller call the component controllers.

What would be the Laravel way to do this?

Comment: Not sure how you structured your default layout but [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) can help with this.

Comment: aha .. yeah so I could do

1) Route direct mapping to the page layout controller
2) get the data through models
3) register the page layout view composer so when the page layout is rendered, a callback is fired
4) in the callback I can loop through the components, call each view (maybe also with a view composer) and then return the html back to the page layout view.